Tracking Python code execution by printing accessed functions
I have an extensive Python project with many files. With the aim of debugging, I want to be able to run my program and have the names of the executed functions printed to the terminal. Is there a special way to call the Python file which does this?
I know of the solution concerning creating a printing function and decorating my functions to print their name on execution but since I have a large code manually decorating every function is lot. Is there some way to call the Python file in a way that it prints every accessed function?

Use sys.settrace to set a trace function on 'call' events.

Based on wim's solution, here is my function:
def my_tracer(frame, event, arg=None):
    # only respond to 'call' events
    if event != 'call':
        return

    # extracts frame code 
    code = frame.f_code 
  
    # extracts calling function name 
    func_name = code.co_name 

    # extracts the filename where function is defined
    filename = code.co_filename

    # handle relative paths
    if not os.path.isabs(filename):
        filename = os.path.abspath(filename)

    # filter to only show functions inside some directory
    desired_directory = os.getcwd()
    if not os.path.commonpath([filename, desired_directory]).startswith(desired_directory):
        return

    # extracts the line number 
    line_no = frame.f_lineno 
  
    print(f"A {event} encountered in {func_name}() at line number {line_no}")

    return my_tracer 

And then
if __name__ == "__main__":
    settrace(my_tracer) 

